# Is there a way to sum all the given keys in an array? JS

Tags: arrays, object, for-loop, sum

So I recently learned that you can use objects as a data type in an array. 
So what I need to do is loop through this array, and add each age, then divide age sum by the length of the array to get an average age of all people. Thing is I don't understand how you would call a given key.

I understand that to call the first object, you would write "people[0]" but I have no idea how to get the key from that object and pass that to a function.

```
let people=[ {name:'Don', Age:23},
             {name:'Ron', Age:21}, 
             {name:'Juan', Age:20}
             ]

// return /people.length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the age and then divide by length of array to get avg value, in this case you can simply used Array.map()

```js
   let people=[ 
             {name:'Don', Age:23},
             {name:'Ron', Age:21}, 
             {name:'Juan', Age:20}]
    //Sum
    let sum = 0;
    //Map
    people.map((value)=> { 
     sum += value.Age; 
    })
    //Average Result
    let avg_Age = sum / people.length
    console.log('Average Age', avg_Age)
```

Answer (score 1):

hope this may help.

```
let people=[ {name:'Don', Age:23},
         {name:'Ron', Age:21}, 
         {name:'Juan', Age:20}
       ];

var totalPeople = people.length;
var totalAge = 0
var averageAge = 0;

for (var key in people) {
  // skip loop if the property is from prototype
  if (!people.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

  var obj = people[key];
  for (var prop in obj) {
    // skip loop if the property is from prototype
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

    if(prop == 'Age') {
      totalAge += obj[prop];
    }
  }
}

averageAge = totalAge / totalPeople;
alert(averageAge);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to traverse through the object and access keys:
    let sum = 0;

```
for(let i=1;i<=people.length;i++) {
sum = sum + people[i-1].Age;
}
console.log(sum/people.length);

//output
21.333333333333332
```

You can also use foreach method to traverse the array.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp
Go through this link here you can find all the methods for array/object manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

To get the keys call `Object.keys(people[0])`

Please take a look `Object.keys` method
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys